# Small subgroup confinement attack on Diffie-Hellman

Tags: cryptanalysis, diffie-hellman, key-exchange, algebraic-attack

I am trying to understand the [small subgroup confinement attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_subgroup_confinement_attack) on the [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) algorithm. I will present the attack and try to explain why it works.

#### Small subgroup confinement attack on the Diffie-Hellman algorithm

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ be a group, where $p$ is a large prime and let $\alpha$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. Let's consider that Alice and Bob want to do a key agreement on the whole cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ using the Diffie-Hellman algorithm. The following sequence diagram illustrates how Eve can perform a small subgroup confinement attack:

[image: Small subgroup attack on Diffie-Hellman key-exchange]

By doing this, if $k$ is well-chosen, the secret $S$ can be found by exhaustive search.

#### How to choose the $k$-value

As $p$ is a prime number, the order of $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ is a composite, so there exist subgroups. Say $\mathbb{G}_w$ is one small subgroup of prime order $w$. So by picking $k = \frac{p-1}{w}$, the secret value $S \in \mathbb{G}_w$ can be found by exhaustive search, efficiently, in the small subgroup $\mathbb{G}_w$.

#### Why does it work?

In this section I will try to prove that $S \in \mathbb{G}_w$.

We know that $w\text{ | } (p-1)$, so $\exists k$ such that $p-1 = w \times k$. Plus, we know that $\mathsf{ord}(\alpha) = p - 1$ because $\alpha$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ and a consequence of [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) is that, given an element $x$, $\mathsf{ord}(x^k) = \frac{\mathsf{ord}(x)}{(\mathsf{ord}(x) \wedge k)}$.
(Here, $\wedge$ denotes the greatest common divisor between two numbers.) So, in our case, we have:

$$\mathsf{ord}(\alpha^{ab(p-1)/w}) = \mathsf{ord}(\alpha^{abk}) = \frac{\mathsf{ord}(\alpha)}{(\mathsf{ord}(\alpha) \wedge abk)} = \frac{(p-1)}{((p-1) \wedge abk)} = \frac{wk}{ (wk \wedge abk)}$$

And, we know that $(wk \wedge abk) = k$, because $w$ is a prime number. Therefore,

$$\mathsf{ord}(\alpha^{ab(p-1)/w}) = \frac{wk}{k} = w$$

As a result, we can conclude that $S \in \mathbb{G}_w$.

**Could someone approve or disapprove my demo**?

Comment: Here's a simpler way to see it: using the fact that $\alpha^k \in \mathbb{G}_w$ that you've already proved, you know that $A^k = (\alpha^k)^x \in \mathbb{G}_w$.  Since the (new) $K$ is a power of $A^k$, it also lives in $\mathbb{G}_w$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof provided in the question is correct, but as [Chris Peikert](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/14958/chris-peikert) pointed out in comments, there is an easier way to prove that $S \in \mathbb{G}_w$:

$ord(\alpha^k) = \frac{ord(\alpha)}{ord(\alpha) \wedge k} = \frac{p - 1}{(p-1) \wedge k} = \frac{p - 1}{k} = w$ so it implies that $\alpha^k \in \mathbb{G}_w$.

As $A^k = (\alpha^a)^k = (\alpha^k)^a$ is a power of $\alpha^k$, it also implies that $A^k \in \mathbb{G}_w$.

In the same way, $S$ is a power of $A^k$ so $S \in \mathbb{G}_w$.